# Typescript callback is null

Tags: typescript, callback

I have a Typescript class with a "public" method (syncItemsWithServer). This method call another "private" method from this class asynchronously (self.getItemsToSync).

**class.ts**

```
        public syncItemsWithServer(DoOnComplete: Function) {
            let self = this;
            let strDBName = "dbname";

            self.getItemsToSync(strDBName, function (obj: any) {
                if (!obj || obj.length == 0) {
                    DoOnComplete(0); //Is null
                    return;
                }

                //... Code
            }
        }
```

**index.html**

```
<script>    
    var c = new class();
    c.syncItemsWithServer(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
</script>
```

I get a javascript error when "DoOnComplete(0)" is called because DoOnComplete is null. The error is "object expected".

I guess the reason is that the code in "syncItemsWithServer" is called synchronously?

How can I correct this?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Is this the exact code you have or a simplified version? Add `console.log(DoOnComplete)` lines in the start of the `syncItemsWithServer` method, and then another one in the first line of the callback function you pass to `getItemsToSync`. What do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your response. You helped me by saying that my code was fine :) I checked the code in "index.html" and I found an silent error in another function. That caused the problem.